# Do/Should you consider GM releases as final?

Tags: apple, beta, ios

I was wondering that, as a developer, you consider a GM release the final release and if you do it for serious development or if you stick to the stable version. With the iOS SDK, you're able to submit apps to Apple for submission to the App Store using a GM version. Do you recommend using the GM version of an SDK or waiting a couple of weeks and use the stable version?

Comment: For those, like me, who aren't sure what "GM" stands for it's "Golden Master". I guess the nearest Microsoft equivalent would be RTM (Release To Manufacture).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on a lot of factors - how paranoid you are, how urgently you need to use the SDK etc.

If my understanding is correct GM (or Golden Master) like Microsoft's RTM (Release To Manufacture) *should* be identical to the product that is finally released as *the* product.

So if you need to have something ready on day one you should be able to use the GM (or RTM) release to build your application so it's good to go immediately.